# iptables ruleset blocking LAN and WAN

Tags: networking, drivers, server, dhcp, static-ip

*Having problems with your Intel I217-V ethernet port? I suggest you read this entire post. Whilst drivers were not my issue, nor my answer (in the end), this post will still provide useful insight.*

In other flavours of Debian that I've used, I would simply edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to force a static IP. However, I can't seem to that in Ubuntu Server 14.04!

My `/etc/network/interface` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1
iface em1 inet static
      address 192.168.0.5
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 192.168.0.0
      broadcast 192.168.0.255
      gateway 192.168.0.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

I've got `dns-nameservers` in there as to my understanding, this will resolve the issue of `/etc/resolv.conf` being wiped upon each initalisation of the NIC. Plus, I can't seem to remove the dhcp-client in Ubuntu 14.04, along with being unable to restart the networking service - I have to `ifdown` and `ifup` for changes to take affect.

So anyway, a little more on my issue. If I of course revert back to using dhcp by changing `static` to `dhcp`, then problem solved. I can ping the router, all connected nodes on LAN and get Internet access. Although, I can't when statically configured with the above, despite the settings being identical to eachother when looking at `ifconfig`.

To my limited knowledge, I'd say this has high relevance to being a DNS issue. Can someone please shed some light? It's driving me nuts.

If it's any consolation, I have SSH Guard installed and it has its own chain in iptables.

**Update: The following paragraph isn't relevant to my question, but more of a solution if anybody experiences issue with their Intel I217-V ethernet adapter and believe it's driver related. The paragraph after the links will progress to detail the rest of my issue...**

OK, turns out it was my iptables ruleset.

However, I think it is incredibly important to note here that the increasing and recent developement there is the for e1000e drivers of the Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 05). Below is 1 driver made by Intel, and the other is a community based. The community based seems to be preferable according to many blogs and forum posts I've read this evening. Give them ago if you fear your problems derive from a suspect driver issue.

Intel ~ https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=15817

Community based ~ http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/latest/download

...progressing on to more relevant matters... If I commented out the `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` in my `interfaces` file, I had no problems what so ever. DHCP or static. So the question is, what is in my ruleset to be so connectivity-paranoid?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat May  3 01:24:30 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [491:1788008]
:sshguard - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j sshguard
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1019 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8112 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58846 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 62598 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-P INPUT DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May  3 01:24:30 2014
```

Comment: Can you ping your router (by IP address) when you're using a static IP address? Also, could you post the output of `nm-tool` while you're using DHCP?

Comment: I cannot ping router when statically configured. And yes, I will update answer in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen done. Though I should note that I can no longer ping gateway... Very confused. It was working fine when I hopping between static and dhcp ~10 minutes ago.

Comment: Okay, it's not a DNS problem because pinging an IP address directly doesn't involve DNS. Could you tell me what network card you're using (you can look it up by executing `lspci`)?

Comment: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 05) - I'm going for a Google hunt now. Didn't think it could be drivers.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen forgive my typo. Just corrected it from e1000c > e1000e

Comment: Is the address specified outside the DHCP range used in the router? I doubt you need the network or broadcast lines at all.

Comment: @chili555 I've just this moment worked it out. It was my iptables ruleset that I import at the end of my `interfaces` file, it was supposedly blocking all possible connections... I will post that up shortly. I've just wasted around two hours of life on this.

Comment: And learned a lot in the process, I'll wager. Glad it's working by whatever means.